# How to differentiate between two nstableviews in same window

Tags: cocoa, osx-mavericks, nstableview, nsnotifications

I am having a problem differentiating between two NSTableViews and could use some help.

I have tried these approaches:

1.

```
- (void)tableViewSelectionDidChange:(NSNotification *)notification {

    if ([[notification object] tag] == 0) {
 NSInteger row = [self.categoryTableView selectedRow];
       ...do stuff

    } else {
        if ([[notification object] tag] == 1 ) {
            [self showItemSheet:self];
        }
    }
}
```

and 2:

```
- (void)tableViewSelectionDidChange:(NSNotification *)notification {

    if ([notification object] == categoryTableView) {
        NSInteger row = [self.categoryTableView selectedRow];

        ..do stuff

    } else {

        if ([notification object] == itemTable ) {
            [self showItemSheet:self];
        }
    }
}
```

Both approaches work - most of the time. However, if I keep selecting from the tableview with tag 0, every three or four clicks and I see the itemSheet table initiated.

Comment: What do you mean it initiated? What's the problem exactly?

Comment: I'll try to be clearer - I select an item in the category table, and the itemSheet opens. I only want the itemSheet to open if an itemTable object is selected.

Comment: Can you try using a delegate method instead of the notification to achieve what you want? From the code above everything *looks* fine so probably the error is elsewhere?

Comment: This is exactly what I ended up doing. If you change this to an answer, I will mark it correct.

Comment: Great, glad that worked. Maybe you can add a comment to the answer as to what you tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try using a delegate method instead of the notification to achieve what you want? From the code above everything looks fine so probably the error is elsewhere?